# Client IP based exception to Spring login

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm trying to get Spring security authentication working on a web application.

So far I've been able to lock down the web app (require the user to log in) for the whole web app except for a URL based exception that I need to have.

```
<http use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/open/**" access="permitAll"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
    <form-login />
</http>
```

This works fine.

However, what I need now is to be able to say that if a client connection is coming from 'localhost' or '127.0.0.1' it should just allow access.

In other words, can I specify that connections coming from localhost don't need any authentication at all while all other (external) connections need to go by the above rules?

Answer (score 1):

Try to define a new role for `localhost` like `ROLE_LOCALHOST` and then configure your `spring-security.xml` like :

```
<http use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/**"
        access="hasRole('ROLE_LOCALHOST') and hasIpAddress('127.0.0.1')"/>
    ...
</http>
```

This will allow you to access to all the URLs for ROLE with `ROLE_LOCALHOST` and IP as `127.0.0.1`. Not so sure about `localhost`.

Comment: Maybe just like this `access="isAuthenticated() or hasIpAddress('127.0.0.1')"`?

Comment: Totally upto you. I would suggest a new role for `LOCALHOST` though. It's a better approach. :) .. But you can try out both. Hope it helps. :)

Comment: I cannot believe I missed that! I did not notice that you could put an and/or in between there!

isAuthenticated() or hasIpAddress('127.0.0.1') seems to work like a charm.